# In-App Purchase - Know When User Clicks 'Buy'

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, uialertview, storekit

I'm trying to show/hide an activity indicator at appropriate times during the transaction process, and I'd like to show the activity indicator after the user clicks 'Buy' on the confirmation alert. This is what I'd like to do:

1. Show after 'Buy' is clicked
2. Hide when Apple ID password dialog is
   shown
3. Show after password is entered

I have the other parts covered, but I can't find the right methods which handle these events. FYI, I am using the DejalBezelActivityView library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check out this, It may help you in finding what you want

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases